# Node express server not affected by sinon's useFakeTimers

Tags: node.js, express, sinon

I am attempting to upgrade from node version 12.x to 16.x. In the new version of node the express server doesn't take sinon's fake timers into account for setting the date header in the response. I've reduced it down the following example:

```
const {test} = require('tap');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const express = require('express');
const {useFakeTimers} = require('sinon');

test('test date header', async t => {
  const port = 17358;
  const path = '/test';
  let app = express();
  app.set('etag', false);
  app.set('x-powered-by', false);
  let server = app.listen(port);
  app.get(path, (req, res) => {
    res.send('OK');
  });

  let clock = useFakeTimers({toFake: ['Date']});
  let response = await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:${port}/${path}`);  

  t.equals(response.headers.get('date'), new Date().toUTCString());
  clock.restore();
  await server.close();
});
```

When I run this in version 16 of node, the test fails because the header set in the response is the current date and not `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT` which I would expect due to the use of the fake timers. In version 12 of node this test does pass.

What causes this change in behaviour and what would be an alternative for getting a predictable 'date' header in the response during testing.

Comment: What sinon version are you using? Has it changed compared to the version used with Node 12?

Comment: No the sinon version stayed the same. The only difference was the node version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a known limitation - the change being between Node v15.1.0 and v15.2.0. The issue being that node http caches a direct reference to `DatePrototypeToUTCString`

See HTTP Date header time faking fails on Node 15.2.0 and later - https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/344

Unfortunately they conclude that -

```
"...the only way forward is to ignore the HTTP Date header."
```

Comment: That seems like it!